# STI with Ploymorphic association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphic-associations, single-table-inheritance

I have model named `Slider`

```
class Slider < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

and `HomeBannerSlider` which has single table inheritance relation with slider

```
class HomeBannerSlider < Slider

    has_many :images, as: :imageable
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

end
```

and `Image` model as given

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
   has_attached_file :image
end
```

My problem is whenever I save `HomeBannerSlider` with following command

```
      @admin_home_banner_slider = HomeBannerSlider.new(admin_home_banner_slider_params)

     @admin_home_banner_slider.save
```

It saves the `imageable_type` in `Image` model as `Slider`

```
@admin_home_banner_slider.images
<Image:0x007f5e6ef7af20
  id: nil,
  imageable_id: nil,
  imageable_type: "Slider",
  title: "2",
  description: "2",
  link_button: nil,
  link_button_title: nil,
  owner: nil,
  publish: nil,
  priority: nil,
  created_at: nil,
  updated_at: nil,
  image_file_name: nil,
  image_content_type: nil,
  image_file_size: nil,
  image_updated_at: nil>]
```

but i want it to store `imageable_type` as `HomeBannerSlider`

Comment: do you have a type column in the slider table?

Comment: yes @TomWalpole ,  and in `type` column it stores correctly `HomeBannerSlider` but in each instance of image it stores `Slider` in `imageable_type` column

Answer (score 1):

From the activerecord documentation -  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Polymorphic+Associations - "Using polymorphic associations in combination with single table inheritance (STI) is a little tricky. In order for the associations to work as expected, ensure that you store the base model for the STI models in the type column of the polymorphic association".

So rails specifically wants the base type stored there, it will still load the correct type if you access my_image.imageable since it uses the type from the Slider table when creating that object and ids are unique for the whole Slider table, not just in each type in the table.

That all being said, there is a gem that adds the behavior you want to rails - https://github.com/appfolio/store_base_sti_class

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in your `Image` model:

```
before_validation :set_type

def set_type
  self.imageable_type = imageable.class.name
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the imageable_type in your model as

```
def imageable_type=(imageType)
  super(imageType.classify.constantize.base_class.to_s)
end
```